# Flutter - GetIt error, Even when it's already Registered

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, clean-architecture, flutter-get

I am writing an app using clean architecture and using GetIt to handle the dependency Injection, now every time i try to start the app it gives this error , telling me that i didn't register 'UserRemoteDataSourceImpl ' when i already did , you can see in the code below

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building Builder:
Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type UserRemoteDataSourceImpl is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
```

Full Error:

```
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7978): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore( 7978): (24.5.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
I/flutter ( 7978): Error while creating BaseAuthFirebaseRepository
I/flutter ( 7978): Stack trace:
I/flutter ( 7978):  #0      throwIfNot
I/flutter ( 7978): #1      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType
I/flutter ( 7978): #2      _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #3      _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #4      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
I/flutter ( 7978): #5      _ServiceFactory.getObject
I/flutter ( 7978): #6      _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #7      _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #8      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
I/flutter ( 7978): #9      _ServiceFactory.getObject
I/flutter ( 7978): #10     _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #11     _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #12     InjectorContainer.init.<
I/flutter ( 7978): Error while creating GetCurrentUserUseCase
I/flutter ( 7978): Stack trace:
I/flutter ( 7978):  #0      throwIfNot
I/flutter ( 7978): #1      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType
I/flutter ( 7978): #2      _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #3      _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #4      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
I/flutter ( 7978): #5      _ServiceFactory.getObject
I/flutter ( 7978): #6      _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #7      _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #8      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
I/flutter ( 7978): #9      _ServiceFactory.getObject
I/flutter ( 7978): #10     _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #11     _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #12     InjectorContainer.init.<
I/flutter ( 7978): Error while creating AuthCubit
I/flutter ( 7978): Stack trace:
I/flutter ( 7978):  #0      throwIfNot
I/flutter ( 7978): #1      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType
I/flutter ( 7978): #2      _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #3      _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #4      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
I/flutter ( 7978): #5      _ServiceFactory.getObject
I/flutter ( 7978): #6      _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #7      _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #8      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
I/flutter ( 7978): #9      _ServiceFactory.getObject
I/flutter ( 7978): #10     _GetItImplementation.get
I/flutter ( 7978): #11     _GetItImplementation.call
I/flutter ( 7978): #12     InjectorContainer.init.<

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building Builder:
Bad state: GetIt: Object/factory with type UserRemoteDataSourceImpl is not registered inside GetIt. 
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)

The relevant error-causing widget was
MaterialApp
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      throwIfNot
#1      _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType
#2      _GetItImplementation.get
#3      _GetItImplementation.call
#4      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
#5      _ServiceFactory.getObject
#6      _GetItImplementation.get
#7      _GetItImplementation.call
#8      InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
#9      _ServiceFactory.getObject
#10     _GetItImplementation.get
#11     _GetItImplementation.call
#12     InjectorContainer.init.<anonymous closure>
#13     _ServiceFactory.getObject
#14     _GetItImplementation.get
#15     _GetItImplementation.call
#16     EuroImpiantiSrls.build.<anonymous closure>
#17     _CreateInheritedProviderState.value
#18     _InheritedProviderScopeElement.value
#19     Provider.of
#20     ReadContext.read
#21     _BlocBuilderBaseState.initState
#22     StatefulElement._firstBuild
#23     ComponentElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (220 frames)
#243    Element.inflateWidget
#244    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
#245    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (426 frames)
#671    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#678    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#685    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#692    _NestedHookElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#699    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#706    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#713    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#720    _NestedHookElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#727    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#734    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#741    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#748    _NestedHookElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#755    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#762    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#769    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#776    _NestedHookElement.mount
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#783    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
...     Normal element mounting (33 frames)
#816    Element.inflateWidget
#817    Element.updateChild
#818    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild
#819    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount
#820    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure>
#821    BuildOwner.buildScope
#822    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
#823    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget
#824    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure>
#828    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Even when i already registered it:

```
----------
## 

 - `Heading`

 ##

GetIt sl = GetIt.instance;

class InjectorContainer {
  static void init() {
    //! Firebase
    sl.registerLazySingleton<FirebaseFirestore>(
        () => FirebaseFirestore.instance);
    sl.registerLazySingleton<FirebaseAuth>(() => FirebaseAuth.instance);
    sl.registerLazySingleton<FirebaseMessaging>(
        () => FirebaseMessaging.instance);

    //! datasources
    sl.registerLazySingleton<BaseUserRemoteDataSource>(() =>
        UserRemoteDataSourceImpl(sl<FirebaseFirestore>(), sl<FirebaseAuth>(),
            sl<FirebaseMessaging>()));

    sl.registerLazySingleton<BaseProductsRemoteDataSources>(
        () => ProductsRemoteDataSources(sl(), sl()));

    //! repository
    sl.registerLazySingleton<BaseAuthFirebaseRepository>(
        () => UserAuthRepositoryImpl(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton<BaseProductsPublicRepository>(
        () => ProductPublicRepositoryImpl(sl()));

    //! usecases
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetCurrentUserUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => IsSignedInUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => LoginWithPhoneUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => OTPVerificationUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => SignOutUserUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => SignUpWithPhoneUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetCurrentUidUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => UpdateLastLoginTimeUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetHomeScreenProductsUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetFavouriteProductsUseCase(sl()));
    sl.registerLazySingleton(() => GetProductImagesUseCase(sl()));

    //! Cubit / Bloc
    sl.registerFactory<NavBarScreensBloc>(() => NavBarScreensBloc());
    sl.registerFactory<AuthCubit>(
        () => AuthCubit(sl(), sl(), sl(), sl(), sl()));
    sl.registerFactory<UserCubit>(() => UserCubit(sl(), sl(), sl()));
    sl.registerFactory<PublicProductsCubit>(
        () => PublicProductsCubit(sl(), sl(), sl()));
  }
}
```

and here is the Code: UserRemoteDataSourceImpl

```
abstract class BaseUserRemoteDataSource {
  Future<bool> isSignedIn();
  Future<void> signOut();
  Future<String?> loginWithPhone(String phoneNum);
  Future<void> signUpWithPhone(UserEntity userEntity);
  Future<bool> otpVerification(String otpNum, String verificationId);
  Future<UserEntity> getCurrentUser();
  Future<String> getCurrentUid();
  Future<void> updateLastLoginTime();
  Future<String> getFcmToken();
}

class UserRemoteDataSourceImpl extends BaseUserRemoteDataSource {
  final FirebaseAuth auth;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;

  UserRemoteDataSourceImpl(this.firestore, this.auth, this.firebaseMessaging);

  @override
  Future<UserEntity> getCurrentUser() async {
    final String userUid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
    return await firestore
        .collection(kUserCollection)
        .doc(userUid)
        .get()
        .then((snapShot) {
      return UserModel.fromSnapshot(snapShot);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> isSignedIn() async => auth.currentUser?.uid != null;

  @override
  Future<String> loginWithPhone(String phoneNum) async {
    final completer = Completer<String>();
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNum,
      verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) async {
        await auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        completer.complete(phoneAuthCredential.verificationId);
      },
      verificationFailed: (error) {},
      codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) async {
        //! complete waits untill the function returns a value
        completer.complete(verificationId);
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {},
    );
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> otpVerification(String otpNum, String verificationId) async {
    final completer = Completer<bool>();
    PhoneAuthCredential credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: otpNum,
    );
    await auth.signInWithCredential(credentials).then((value) {
      firestore
          .collection(kUserCollection)
          .doc(value.user!.uid)
          .snapshots()
          .listen((snapShot) {
        if (snapShot.exists) {
          completer.complete(false);
        } else {
          completer.complete(true);
        }
      });
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signUpWithPhone(UserEntity userEntity) async {
    await firestore.collection(kUserCollection).doc(userEntity.uid).set({
      kUserName: userEntity.name,
      kUserPhone: userEntity.phone,
      kUserUid: userEntity.uid,
      kUserRegisterTime: Timestamp.now(),
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async => await auth.signOut();

  @override
  Future<String> getCurrentUid() async => auth.currentUser!.uid;

  @override
  Future<void> updateLastLoginTime() async {
    await firestore
        .collection(kUserCollection)
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .update({
      kLastLoginTime: Timestamp.now(),
      kFcmToken: await getFcmToken(),
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<String> getFcmToken() async {
    final completer = Completer<String>();
    NotificationSettings settings = await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      completer.complete(await firebaseMessaging.getToken());
    }
    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make sure that the object is registered before or not
using

```dart
GetIt.I.isRegistered<TYPE>()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

IT got resolved by removing  before registering the Dependency